# Capturar div pela class

Tags: php, libcurl, php-domdocument

Estou tentando capturar uma div apartir de sua classe porem nao obtive exito, observe: eu tento capturar a div com a classe `class='m-definicao-conteudo'` do site que informo ao curl, porem me retorna esse error:

> Warning:
>   DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : a in Entity, line: 102 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/teste.php on line 13

```
$ch = curl_init ("");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://dicionarioinformal.com.br/aham/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.2.14912/870; U; id) Presto/2.4.15"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='m-definicao-conteudo']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Parece que o HTML não está em condições ou não está a ser recolhido na totalidade.

Comment: Estranho pois ele é recolhido inteiro pelo curl

Answer (score 3):

Altere o USER_AGENT.

Altere:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.2.14912/870; U; id) Presto/2.4.15");
```

Para:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36");
```

Você pode alterar para qualquer outro, desde que seja um navegador de Desktop.

Utilizando o atual(Opera Mini) o site está redirecionando para o modelo 'mobile' do site, que não contem a div. ;)

Comment: +1 Boa, nem tinha visto o UA em uso :)

Answer (score 2):

O teu problema parece-me ser a forma como estás a passar o nome da `class` a ser localizada:

```
$html = '<div>Ora que raio!</div>
<p>Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc. Meu nome é assim pq sim</p>
<div class="minhaClasse">Encontrei</div>
<p></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$class = 'minhaClasse'; // guarda nome da classe numa variavel

$procura = new DomXPath($dom); // instancia o DomXPath

$div = $procura->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]"); // Procura passando a variavel
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hCdsBH):

```
var_dump($div->item(0)->nodeValue); // string(9) "Encontrei"
```

Comment: Fiz como me mostrou e retornou os mesmos erros, qual problema de meu curl?

Comment: Hmm... Dificil de dizer sem fazer testes com o teu código... mas aqui são 4:30h da manhã, já não tenho cabeça para ver isso a esta hora. Tentarei ajudar mais amanhã!

Comment: Boa noite, ate!